# TypeError: Cannot read property 'addCompany' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

tengo un problema en mi aplicación cuando quiero añadir una compañía al sistema.

Cuando introduzco todos los campos pertinentes y le doy a guardar me saca el error del titulo (adjunto foto del error).
[image: Error addCompany]

He buscado por internet para solucionar el error pero no lo he conseguido. He visto a personas que tenían el mismo error, pero la mayoría de las soluciones que daban no valían para mi caso, o eso me pareció. Algunas probé a implementarlas en mi caso pero seguía saliendo el error.

Adjunto también el código.

actions.js:

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';
import backend from '../../backend';
import * as selectors from './selectors';

const addedCompanyCompleted = companyId => ({
    type: actionTypes.ADDED_COMPANY_COMPLETED,
    companyId
});

export const addCompany = (name, capacity, reserve, homeSale, reservePercentage, 
companyCategoryId, 
    onSuccess, onErrors) => dispatch =>
    backend.companyService.addCompany(name, capacity, reserve, homeSale, reservePercentage, companyCategoryId, 
        ({id}) => {
            dispatch(addedCompanyCompleted(id));
            onSuccess();
        },
        onErrors);

const findAllCompanyCategoriesCompleted = companyCategories => ({
    type: actionTypes.FIND_ALL_COMPANY_CATEGORIES_COMPLETED,
    companyCategories
});

export const findAllCompanyCategories = () => (dispatch, getState) => {

    const companyCategories = selectors.getCompanyCategories(getState());

    if (!companyCategories) {

        backend.companyService.findAllCompanyCategories(
            companyCategories => dispatch(findAllCompanyCategoriesCompleted(companyCategories))
        );

    }

}
```

AddCompany.js:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {FormattedMessage} from 'react-intl';
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

import {Errors} from '../../common';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import CategorySelectorAddCompany from './CategorySelectorAddCompany';

const AddCompany = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const history = useHistory();
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [capacity, setCapacity] = useState(1);
    const [reserve, setReserve] = useState('');
    const [homeSale, setHomeSale] = useState('');
    const [reservePercentage, setReservePercentage] = useState(0);
    const [companyCategoryId, setCompanyCategoryId]  = useState('');
    const [backendErrors, setBackendErrors] = useState(null);
    let form;

    const handleSubmit = event => {

        event.preventDefault();

        if (form.checkValidity()) {
            
            dispatch(actions.addCompany(name.trim(),
                capacity, reserve, homeSale,reservePercentage,1,
                () => history.push('/users/login'),
                errors => setBackendErrors(errors)));

        } else {

            setBackendErrors(null);
            form.classList.add('was-validated');

        }
    }

    const toNumber = value => value.length > 0 ? Number(value) : null;

    return (
        <div class="container">
            <div className="row justify-content-center" >
                <aside className="col-sm-6">
                    <Errors errors={backendErrors} onClose={() => setBackendErrors(null)}/>
                    <div className="card">
                        <article className="card-body">
                            <h4 className="card-title mb-4 mt-1">Añade tu empresa</h4>
                            <br/>
                            <form ref={node => form = node} className="needs-validation" 
                                noValidate onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label for="name">Nombre: </label>
                                    <input type="text" id="name" className="form-control" 
                                        value={name}
                                        onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                                        autoFocus
                                        required/>
                                    <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                        <FormattedMessage id='project.global.validator.required'/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label for="capacity">Capacidad: </label>
                                    <input type="number" id="capacity" min="1" step ="1" className="form-control" 
                                        placeholder="Name"
                                        value={capacity}
                                        onChange={e => setCapacity(e.target.value)}
                                        autoFocus
                                        required/>
                                    <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                        <FormattedMessage id='project.global.validator.required'/>
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                                <CategorySelectorAddCompany id="companyCategoryId" className="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2"
                                value={companyCategoryId} 
                                onChange={e => setCompanyCategoryId(e.target.value)}/>
                                <div>
                                    <label for="reserve">Reserva: </label>
                                    <div className="form-check-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" id="reserve" name="reserve" className="form-check-input" 
                                            value={true}
                                            onChange={e => setReserve(e.target.value)}
                                            autoFocus
                                            checked
                                            required/>
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="reserve">Yes</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-check-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" id="reserve2" name="reserve" className="form-check-input" 
                                            value={false}
                                            onChange={e => setReserve(e.target.value)}
                                            autoFocus
                                            required/>
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="reserve2">No</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                        <FormattedMessage id='project.global.validator.required'/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label for="homeSale">Venta a domicilio: </label>
                                    <div className="form-check-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" id="homeSale" name="homeSale" className="form-check-input" 
                                            value={true}
                                            onChange={e => setHomeSale(e.target.value)}
                                            autoFocus
                                            checked
                                            required/>
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="homeSale">Yes</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-check-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" id="homeSale2" name="homeSale" className="form-check-input" 
                                            value={false}
                                            onChange={e => setHomeSale(e.target.value)}
                                            autoFocus
                                            required/>
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="homeSale2">No</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                        <FormattedMessage id='project.global.validator.required'/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label for="reservePercentage">Porcentaje de la señal de reserva: </label>
                                    <input type="number" id="reservePercentage" min="0" step ="1" className="form-control" 
                                        value={reservePercentage}
                                        onChange={e => setReservePercentage(e.target.value)}
                                        autoFocus
                                        required/>
                                    <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                        <FormattedMessage id='project.global.validator.required'/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br/>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col">
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">Guardar</button>
                                        </div> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                                              
                            </form>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </aside> 
            </div>
        </div> 
    );

}

export default AddCompany;
```

backend/companyService.js :

```
import {config, appFetch} from './appFetch';

export const addCompany = (name, capacity, reserve, homaSale, reservePercentage, companyCategoryId, 
    onSuccess, onErrors) =>
    appFetch(`/companies/add`,
        config('POST', {name, capacity, reserve, homaSale, reservePercentage, companyCategoryId}),
        onSuccess, onErrors);

export const modifyCompany = (company, onSuccess, onErrors) =>
    appFetch(`/companies/${company.id}`, config('PUT', company),
        onSuccess, onErrors);

export const deregister = (id, onSuccess, onErrors) =>
    appFetch(`/companies/${id}/deregister`, 
        config('POST'), onSuccess, onErrors);

export const findAllCompanyCategories = (onSuccess) => 
appFetch('/companies/categories', config('GET'), onSuccess);
```

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Como cargas backend.companyService? Porque por lo visto no está definido.

Comment: Hola, en `actions.js`, arriba hago primero `import backend from '../../backend';`. Acabo de adjuntar el código de `backend/companyServices.js` por si te sirve de ayuda. Un saludo

Comment: Tienes alguna inded.js dentro de la carpeta `backend`? Porque veo que importas `import backend from '../../backend';` pero en el codigo que compartes dices que tu ruta es `backend/companyService.js`. Ademas tendrias que acceder a `backend.addCompany` porque no veo que tengas algo llamado `companyService` dentro de backend.